# Automatically recognize unit prefix in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I often embed some elementary computations directly into my latex source via pythontex. I follow the convention that I give all numbers in my script in SI-units (eg. seconds not nanoseconds or kilogram and not gram etc.). From my latex document I can pass variables defined or calculated in my script to siunitx and print it via a command called `\pySI`:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\pySI}{ O{} m m O{}}
{%
\py[#1]{'\\SI[#4]{' + str(#2).replace('(','').replace(')','') + r'}{#3}'}%
}
```

Now suppose I have a variable `l` in my python script (for a length in meter) with the value `l = 2.5e-3`. In the main document however I want the number to be printed in millimeter, then I call it like `\pySI{l*1e3}{\mm}`. This is a bit inconvenient. So I am looking for a way of how to make siunitx to recognize the unit prefix `\milli` such that `\pySI{l}{\mm}` or `\pySI{l}{\mili\meter}` typesets `2.5 mm`. This should work for all prefixes for example `\pySI{l}{\m}` should print `0.0025 m` (or in scientific notation depending on the si settings) or `\pySI{l}{\cm}` should print `0.25 cm`. It should also work for all units defined within siunitx.

Comment: I guess I'll ask python do the job (simply multiply by a power of ten, according to the second mandatory argument).

Comment: Please first provide an MWE.